# $M = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos x}{(x+2)} dx$ and $N = \int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{\sin x \cos x}{(x+1)^2} dx$, then value of $M - N$ is?

Tags: definite-integrals

Options are :
(A) $\pi\quad$   (B) $\frac{\pi}{4}\quad$    (C) $\frac{2}{\pi + 4}\quad$   (D) $\frac{2}{\pi - 4}$

I have solved it using Taylor's expansion of the numerators. 
E.g, $\cos x = \cos ((x+2) -2) = \cos(x+2) \cos 2 + \sin(x+2) \sin 2$, then using Taylor's formula expanded $\cos(x+2)$ and $\sin(x+2)$ to get polynomials of $(x+2)$, which is in the denominator.
But due to the denominator, I am getting results in terms of log, which does not match any of the options given.

Comment: [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Using NIntegrate in Mathematica didn't give anything close to the choices...are you sure you've stated the problem correctly?

Comment: @Integrand. $4$ is a typo. The upper bound must be $\frac \pi 4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Integration by Parts, we can write N as
$$N = -\frac{\sin x\cos x}{x+1}\vert_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}+\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{\cos^2x-\sin^2x}{x+1}dx=-\frac{2}{\pi+4}+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\cos2x}{x+1}dx$$
In the second integral, let $x \to 2x \implies dx \to 2dx$
$$\therefore N=-\frac{2}{\pi+4}+\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\cos x}{x+2}dx=-\frac{2}{\pi+4}+M$$
$$\therefore M-N=\frac{2}{\pi+4}$$

---

P.S Thanks to Claude Leibovici for the corrected expression.

Comment: Thanks Aditya for trying. Since $\frac{\pi}{2}$ < 8, the integral part might be a negative term.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you. Like other people have already mentioned, there might be some error in the question :)

Comment: I do not want to put an answer since you did most of the work. Do you mind to redo your calculation with an upper bound equal to $\frac \pi 4$ for $N$. Thanks and cheers.

Comment: Sure! Will do so immediately! Thanks for finding the corrected expression :)

Comment: You are very welcome ! Nice and simple and elegant solution. $\to +1$.

Comment: Very nice solution. Thank you Aditya.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

The real problem is 
$$N = \int_0^{\color{red}{\frac \pi 4}} \frac{\sin (x) \cos (x)}{(x+1)^2}\, dx$$ and the answer is $(C)$.

Comment: Thanks Claude for correcting. It might be a printing mistake in the paper.